# How do I add hours to Toggl via Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and would like to have a python script that would update Toggl based on the picture below. Note, that I don't want to start/stop the timer (although if you want to through that in, I may use it), but what I really want to do is just simply add time after the fact.

[image]

I just want to pass in:

- text about what I did for the day
- existing project to link to
- duration
- start time
- date

I tried togglwrapper (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/togglwrapper/1.0.1) and connected to my account via API token just fine. I'm just not sure how to send a request to add a time entry.

Answer (score 0):

TogglWrapper does not have the option to create a Time Entry like it is specified in the following endpoint:

https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/time_entries.md#create-a-time-entry

But you can do the same by starting and stopping the timer like this:
In data be sure to include the proper data.

```
>>> from togglwrapper import Toggl
>>> toggl = Toggl('your_api_token')
>>> data = {"time_entry":{"description":"description","tags":["billed"],"pid":123,"created_with":"curl"}}
>>> response = toggl.TimeEntries.start()
```

It will call this API endpoint: https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/time_entries.md#start-a-time-entry

Now get the Time entry ID to stop it.

```
>>> toggl.TimeEntries.stop(response.get('data').get('id'))
```

Hope it helps!